# Mockito is throwing org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: At the moment you cannot provide own implementations of MockHandler

Tags: java, android, kotlin, junit, mockito

While trying to mock an object inside a JUnit test in android, mockito is throwing **org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: At the moment you cannot provide own implementations of MockHandler**

Below is the code of unit test

```
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner

//@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class StoreViewModelTest {

    lateinit var observer: Observer<StoreList>

    @Mock lateinit var storeUseCase: StoreUseCase

    private lateinit var viewModel: StoreViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUp() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        viewModel = StoreViewModel(storeUseCase)
    }

    @Test
    fun loadstore_ExecutesUseCase() {
        viewModel.setId(123)
        verify(storeUseCase, times(1)).execute(any())
    }

}
```

The error is thrown at the statement **MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)**

StackTrace :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: At the moment you cannot provide own implementations of MockHandler.
Please see the javadocs for the MockMaker interface.

at com.app.ui.store.StoreViewModelTest.setUp(StoreViewModelTest.kt:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: might be because you're trying to mock a lateinit.. ? i'm not sure though

Comment: that doesn't seems to be the issue. i tried without it. still wasn't working